# False-positive in the Golang Race Detector? [repost]

Tags: go, concurrency, hashmap, race-condition

I had posted this question a few days ago and it got closed as there was an error in the code. Got that fixed up and so re-posting this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync/atomic"
    "math/rand"
)
//This data is normally fetched via HTTP Request
var dummyData1 = []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
var activeMap = new(int32)
var map1 = make(map[string]*int32)
var map2 map[string]*int32
var combinedMap = make(map[string]*int32)

func mapKeyUpdater () {
    for _, key := range dummyData1 {
        combinedMap[key] = new(int32)
        map1[key] = new(int32)
    }
    atomic.AddInt32(activeMap, 1)
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    for {
        if atomic.LoadInt32(activeMap) == 1 {
            map2 = make(map[string]*int32)
            for _, key := range dummyData1 {
                map2[key] = new(int32)
            }
            atomic.AddInt32(activeMap, 1)
            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) //Added after EDIT. See below
            for key, count := range map1{
                *combinedMap[key] += *count
            }
        } else {
            map1 = make(map[string]*int32)
            for _, key := range dummyData1 {
                map1[key] = new(int32)
            }
            atomic.AddInt32(activeMap, -1)
            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) //Added after EDIT. See below
            for key, count := range map2 {
                *combinedMap[key] += *count
            }
        }
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    }
}

func counter () {
    for {
        randomIndex := rand.Intn(5)
        randomKey := dummyData1[randomIndex]
        if atomic.LoadInt32(activeMap) == 1 {
            val := atomic.AddInt32(map1[randomKey], 100)
            fmt.Printf("Added 100 to %v in Map1. Updated value %v\n", randomKey, val)
        } else {
            val := atomic.AddInt32(map2[randomKey], 100)
            fmt.Printf("Added 100 to %v in Map2. Updated value %v\n", randomKey, val)
        }
    }
}

func main () {
    go mapKeyUpdater()
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    go counter()
    time.Sleep(15 * time.Second)
}
```

Now when I run this with the command `go run -race raceBug.go` I get 4 Race's each time. However, it is clear from the output that there is no race, and the maps are working as intended

```
==================
Added 100 to e in Map2. Updated value 7990900
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x0000011cdbd0 by goroutine 7:
Added 100 to a in Map2. Updated value 7972000
  main.mapKeyUpdater()
      /raceBug.go:34 +0x14d

Previous read at 0x0000011cdbd0 by goroutine 9:
Added 100 to e in Map2. Updated value 7991000
  [failed to restore the stack]

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /raceBug.go:62 +0x29
Added 100 to e in Map2. Updated value 7991100

Goroutine 9 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /raceBug.go:64 +0x44
==================
Added 100 to c in Map2. Updated value 7956400
Added 100 to b in Map2. Updated value 7993400
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Added 100 to e in Map1. Updated value 100
Read at 0x00c00001acec by goroutine 7:
  main.mapKeyUpdater()
      /raceBug.go:40 +0x2d4

Added 100 to c in Map1. Updated value 100
Previous write at 0x00c00001acec by goroutine 9:
  sync/atomic.AddInt32()
      /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.18/libexec/src/runtime/race_amd64.s:279 +0xb
  sync/atomic.AddInt32()
      <autogenerated>:1 +0x1a
Added 100 to d in Map1. Updated value 100

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /raceBug.go:62 +0x29

Added 100 to b in Map1. Updated value 100
Goroutine 9 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /raceBug.go:64 +0x44
==================
```

This article by an engineer at Google says - https://medium.com/@val_deleplace/does-the-race-detector-catch-all-data-races-1afed51d57fb

> If you strongly believe that you witnessed a false positive, then report a bug for the race detector. If you have good reasons to believe that the race condition was caused by the standard library or by the runtime (rather than your own code), then report a bug for the standard library or the runtime.

As I am still pretty new at Go, just want to get some confirmation of this.

EDIT: Just to make sure that the `combinedMap` loop has enough time before it starts, I added a `time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)`. However the Race is still detected, but the output is now different.

New Output

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACEAdded 100 to e in Map2. Updated value 9447300

Write at 0x0000011cdbd0 by goroutine 7:
Added 100 to c in Map2. Updated value 9465100
  main.mapKeyUpdater()
      /raceBug2.go:35 +0x14d

Previous read at 0x0000011cdbd0 by goroutine 9:
Added 100 to b in Map2. Updated value 9461300
  [failed to restore the stack]

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /raceBug2.go:64 +0x29
Added 100 to d in Map2. Updated value 9479400

Goroutine 9 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /raceBug2.go:66 +0x44
Added 100 to c in Map2. Updated value 9465200
==================
```

Comment: You have a data race: atomic operations on a variable only guarantee that each such operation happens atomically with regard to other such operations on the same variable: that is, no read operation will see a partially updated variable. But that is all: atomics do not enforce any ordering, so your "counter" code is free to access the map at the same time "mutating" code updates it. The fact the program produces correct results is irrelevant: it may stop doing that on different hardware, kernel version, system load, version of Go or a combination thereof.

Comment: @kostix I understand that atomic doesnot guarantee ordering, however this is not needed in the code above, as any writes to the old map after update will be accounted for by the loop below.

Go complains that the `combinedMap` loop is accessing the same memory which was touched by `AddInt32`, but that is to be expected in this. I am really not seeing the Data Race here. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I could speculate that you have a wrong mindset regarding memory access synchronisation as supported in Go (and in contemporary hardware). You seem to think that inserting sleeps synchronizes the goroutines but it does not: the runtime is not required to even start the first goroutine in `main` before the second one—or, rather, it's required to execute the first `go` statement before the second one but the first created goroutine is free to be suspended right away and actually start to run its code after the second goroutine completes (!). …

Comment: …It's unlikely to ever experience such extreme behaviour in a toy example like yours while running it in contemporary commodity hardware and OS, but in non-toy real-world examples (say, hundreds or thousands of goroutines with shortage of CPU time) this has a great chance of being observed. Another fact that suggests wrong mindset on your part is that you do not synchronize the goroutines with `main` (which runs on the main goroutine): when `main` ends, all other outstanding goroutines are teared down forcibly, so if any of your goroutines were to spend more time than your sleep timers, …

Comment: …you could easily end up in a situation when any of both of them are shot down dead before they complete they work—when `main` exits having had completed waiting on the last timer. That is, your program has undefined behaviour in two points: the data race and not waiting for the goroutines to complete. Basically both these problems are manifestation of the same problem: execution of goroutines is not properly synchronized. I should repeat that the sole bit of data access to which is synchronized in your code is the `activeMap` variable; everything else is accessed without synchronization.

Comment: For a start, I would recommend to read [this classic piece](http://web.archive.org/web/20210912110157/https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong.html) by one of the devs behind race detector in Go, but really you should at least complete the tour of Go, read [this](https://go.dev/ref/mem)—esp. pay attention to the "Advice" section,—and then move to [this](https://www.amazon.com/Concurrency-Go-Tools-Techniques-Developers/dp/1491941197).

Comment: @kostix Guess my previous reply was deleted, so here goes again. Thanks for your comments, but you seem to have missed the fact the this is just a very simple PoC and not actual prod code. The `sleeps` are placeholders for other code that does verification. Anyway if you have real feedback on my algo, and not personal attacks, lmk

Answer (score 1):

A data race happens when two goroutines access the same variable concurrently, and at least one of the accesses is a write.

In your code, the global vars map1 and map2 are accessed by the two goroutines. Using atomic package to read and operate the map item is not enough because the map items value (pointer of int32) are changed when recreating the map in mapKeyUpdater. Use a Mutex to lock these two maps to eliminate race.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

//This data is normally fetched via HTTP Request
var dummyData1 = []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
var activeMap = new(int32)
var combinedMap = make(map[string]*int32)

type myMap struct {
    mutex sync.RWMutex
    value map[string]*int32
}

var (
    map1 = myMap{
        value: make(map[string]*int32),
    }
    map2 = myMap{}
)

func mapKeyUpdater() {
    for _, key := range dummyData1 {
        combinedMap[key] = new(int32)
        map1.mutex.Lock()
        map1.value[key] = new(int32)
        map1.mutex.Unlock()
    }
    atomic.AddInt32(activeMap, 1)
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    for {
        if atomic.LoadInt32(activeMap) == 1 {
            map2.mutex.Lock()
            map2.value = make(map[string]*int32)
            for _, key := range dummyData1 {
                map2.value[key] = new(int32)
            }
            map2.mutex.Unlock()
            atomic.AddInt32(activeMap, 1)
            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) //Added after EDIT. See below
            map1.mutex.Lock()
            for key, count := range map1.value {
                *combinedMap[key] += *count
            }
            map1.mutex.Unlock()
        } else {
            map1.mutex.Lock()
            for _, key := range dummyData1 {
                map1.value[key] = new(int32)
            }
            map1.mutex.Unlock()
            atomic.AddInt32(activeMap, -1)
            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) //Added after EDIT. See below
            map2.mutex.Lock()
            for key, count := range map2.value {
                *combinedMap[key] += *count
            }
            map2.mutex.Unlock()
        }
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    }
}

func counter() {
    for {
        randomIndex := rand.Intn(5)
        randomKey := dummyData1[randomIndex]
        if atomic.LoadInt32(activeMap) == 1 {
            map1.mutex.Lock()
            val := atomic.AddInt32(map1.value[randomKey], 100)
            map1.mutex.Unlock()
            fmt.Printf("Added 100 to %v in Map1. Updated value %v\n", randomKey, val)
        } else {
            map2.mutex.Lock()
            val := atomic.AddInt32(map2.value[randomKey], 100)
            map2.mutex.Unlock()
            fmt.Printf("Added 100 to %v in Map2. Updated value %v\n", randomKey, val)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    go mapKeyUpdater()
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    go counter()
    time.Sleep(15 * time.Second)
}
```

It should be avoided to using shared variables (like global var) to send value to multiple goroutines. Use channel is the recommended way. Note: using channel to pass pointer is not safe either. Just send value via channel.

[Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating.](https://go.dev/blog/codelab-share)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my code, however, the point of all the jugglery above is to avoid mutex'es & other atomic structures such as channels, syncmaps etc. In my testing the algo above continues to work fine, confirming my suspicions of a false positive.